# Computed size of css font-size with vmin

Tags: html, css

I've got an issue when using vmin for sizing fonts. It looks fine on desktop browsers but when I switch to mobile sizes the computed font-size differs between the textValue divs depending on their parent container.

**Code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
    html {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
    }
    body {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        font-family: sans-serif;
    }
    .main{
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0 auto;
        display: inline;
    }
    .contentWrapper{
        width: 90%;
        margin: 0 auto;
        font-size: 0;
        margin-bottom: 10%;
    }
    .textValue{
        font-size: 3vmin;
    }
    #someForm{
        text-align: center;
    }
    .subMain1{
        display: inline-block;
        width: 50%;
    }
    .subMain2{
        display: inline-block;
        width: 50%;
    }
    @media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width:
    480px) {
        .textValue{
            font-size: 4vmin;
        }
        .subMain1 {
            width: 100%;
        }
        .subMain2 {
            width: 100%;
        }
    }

</style>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="main">
        <div class="contentWrapper">
            <div class="textValue">This is the opening String</div>
            <div class="noCssClass">
                <form id="someForm" name="theForm"> 
                    <div class="subMain1">
                        <div class="textValue">Hello How are things?</div>
                        <div class="textValue">Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="subMain2">
                        <div class="textValue">Hello How are things?</div>
                        <div class="textValue">Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing</div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

All of the textValue containers are set to have a `font-size: 3vmin;` and have a media query to switch this 4vmin. This overrides the parent containers `font-size: 0;` (The 0 font-size is allowing for 2 div "columns" in my actual work to be 50% width)

When this is switched into a small enough mobile mode the vmin is calculating differently for the textValue divs that are nested inside the subMain divs. I've tested this on chrome (desktop responsive dev tools and an older Android device) and IE11 both replicate the issue; the first textValue is smaller then the subMain nested ones.

From testing it looks like the width value that's set on the subMain divs is to blame, as unchecking this value in the dev tools causes the font-size to calculate normally.

Why would the div width affect vmin calculations though? I would expect a DOM elements size to have zero effect on the scaling of a viewport percentage.

**Edit:**

The code example above is 100% complete, the html file has an issue with the vmin size on small (mobile sized) resolutions.

One thing I did notice was that the actual vmin value to notice the discrepancy in the calculated value is most pronounced at about 3.5 or 4; going higher or lower minimized the issue. I'm wondering if overall screen resolution has something to do with it.

I'm adding an image to hopefully clarify the issue I'm seeing:
[image: Web view of the issue with dev tools displaying Vmin value]

**2nd Edit:**

Here's a codepen to make it easier for people to check out the issue. [Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wgJYLq)

Remember the issue only shows up on cell phone type sizes, open up dev tools and switch on the responsive view. In chrome this is the "Toggle Device toolbar" button in the upper left (or Ctrl-Shift-M)

Comment: I either can't reproduce your issue or I don't understand it. Can you put together a live example?

Comment: @SergChernata Codepen added, most noticeable live example I could build.

Comment: Can I suggest that you don't use font size zero but instead do `</div><div class="subMain2">` without a space between the inline elements.

Comment: @Davey That works as well for getting both elements on the same line at 50% (I don't personally like how the code looks in that fashion) but it doesn't address the scaling issue of the vmin based font-size

Comment: I don't have an answer and I'm getting tired of playing with this but if I remove all css except for rules that affect vmin values it all looks good. That tells me that vmin is working just fine, but some of your div sizing rules are affecting it.

Comment: @SergChernata right which they shouldn't, which is why the question is why would div sizing affect vmin scaling? I can fix the dom to make this work in other ways but I'm curious why this is occurring in the first place